# Change Program Not Working with $1.16

Tags: java, casting, truncation

This program makes change except $1.16 why is this not processing correctly?

```
public class Change {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Change: ");
        double change = in.nextDouble()*100;
        int dollars = Math.round((int)change/100);
        change=change%100;
        int quarters = Math.round((int)change/25);
        change=change%25;
        int dimes = Math.round((int)change/10);
        change=change%10;
        int nickels = Math.round((int)change/5);
        change=change%5;
        int pennies = Math.round((int)change/1);

        System.out.println("Dollars: " + dollars);
        System.out.println("Quarters: " + quarters);
        System.out.println("Dimes: " + dimes);
        System.out.println("Nickels: " + nickels);
        System.out.println("Pennies: " + pennies);
    }
}
```

I believe it is a truncating issue because when I use .9 in the following piece of code it works:

```
int pennies = Math.round((int)change/.9);
```

Comment: that's why BigDecimal is used in banking

Comment: Do all your calculations in cents ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is change is a double.  When I ran it I printed out change before the pennies statement this is what printed: 0.9999999999999858.  When this is cast to an int it becomes 0.  So 0 / 1 is 0.  Don't use modulus division with double. When you input 1.16 it returns 1.1599999999999999999999999999999. Try rounding the input up.

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Change: ");
        int change = (int)(Math.ceil(in.nextDouble()*100));
        int dollars = Math.round((int)change/100);
        change=change%100;
        int quarters = Math.round((int)change/25);
        change=change%25;
        int dimes = Math.round((int)change/10);
        change=change%10;
        int nickels = Math.round((int)change/5);
        change=change%5;
        int pennies = Math.round((int)change/1);

        System.out.println("Dollars: " + dollars);
        System.out.println("Quarters: " + quarters);
        System.out.println("Dimes: " + dimes);
        System.out.println("Nickels: " + nickels);
        System.out.println("Pennies: " + pennies);
```

This code works.